# Passing a variable from angular to JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick

I am sure this is fairly simple, but I am stuck.

I am creating a list of my projects for my portfolio and one thing I want is to open a modal when you click on one of the projects.  I know there are probably good ways to do modals that I am overlooking, but I already have this set up.

What I currently have is:

```
<div class="info" onclick="loadModal('{{project.name}}');">
```

But when I render it in chrome, I get:

```
<div class="info" onclick="loadModal('{{project.name}}');" style="height: 317px;">
    ...
</div>
```

instead of the variable being passed.

Is there an easy way to fix this or will I have to do it a completely different way?

Thank you

Comment: I need to see more code to see what is the problem here. I need to see the rest of your template. I would, however, recommend reading about Batarang, a Chrome Extension that helps you debug your Angular apps. You can inspect the div, and see if project.name is actually on the active scope.

Comment: Because it didn't replace {{project.name}} with undefined, it looks like Angular is not running on that section of your page.

Comment: Where do you get the scope variable from? Can you check whether it actually has a value, and post the result?

Comment: The angular stuff is all set up correctly because I am using the same variable somewhere else and it works fine.  I'm thinking its because the onclick is javascript and not html so angular doesn't work

Comment: Is there a specific reason, you cant use `ng-click` instead of `onclick` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pull the function inside scope and do this instead

```
<div class="info" data-ng-click="loadModal(project.name)">
```